# How can i display the password unencrypted in a text input field? . I encrypted password with hash

Tags: php, laravel, hash, md5

I encrypted password with hash

```
 $user->contrasenia = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

In a input I want to show the password unencrypted

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='password' name='password'
```

Comment: Concept failed. Hash is not an encryption method. It's an one-way (in theory) hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, It's a one way hash. By its very design it cannot be unhashed. Only checked against.

You can use:

```
if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted to do it and throw any security to the wind, you would store the plain text version of the hash in your database. But it is **highly** ill advised.

Comment: How does Firefox do it then (you can display all remembered passwords in plain text at a later time)? Does that mean that Ff stores all passwords in plain text?

Comment: I imagine they store the passwords in plain text in a file and then encrypt the whole file with two way encryption. The Firefox Support guide seems to suggest this also: 
`"Even though the Password Manager stores your usernames and passwords on your hard drive in an encrypted format, someone with access to your computer can still see or use them."` https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords

Answer (score 1):

You can't its an one way hashing

To verify a password you may use

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Reference [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#storing-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of hashing passwords, is that it is not possible for you to unhash it. As soon as the user enters their password, a new hash of that input will be created. The two hashes will be compared and if they match, the user is allowed to login.

If you really want to, and I do not recommend this, you could save the password unhashed.

You could also encrypt and decrypt the password. This will make it more secure but it is still not the right way. If you choose to do so, you could use my [Cipher](https://github.com/peterurk/Cipher) class on github.